# T-SQL Default variable values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know this is simple, but I can't seem to find an answer online. Take this piece of code.

```
 declare @year int      
 declare @orderdate datetime    
 set @orderdate = (select orderdate from [table] where [id = variable id])    
 if @orderdate between '01-Apr-2005 00:00' and '31-Mar-2006 23:59'    
  set @year = 2005
```

This hard coded section will assign the year to be 2005 if it is in that date range. Otherwise? Well, I don't know.

I tried adding a print statement to print out the value, but the T-SQL engine just skips over the code. So what *is its value* if the if statement above isn't executed? Can it be described as having a value?

Comment: have you tried PRINT ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, @OrderDate), 'None') for your print statement. Printing NULL is hard to see (blank line)

Comment: @Kamal: No, I'll try that now. I had tried printing a string saying 'year: ' and then concatenating that with the year value - but that skipped the whole line

Comment: string + NULL = NULL in sql-server

Comment: But are you asking about `@year` or `@orderdate`? I understand that you are asking about the former. And its default value is `NULL`, like any other unassigned variable. This: `declare @year int;
print isnull(@year, 12345);` prints "12345". :)

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks, I'd just figured that out. I never tried an isnull. Doing that was simple enough and solved the problem. Definitely everything was initialised to null.

Comment: @Kamal: You should really add that as an answer, since there's nothing suitable here.

Comment: @Kamal, depends on how you concatenate, if you just use '+' operator then yes, it evaluates to NULL. If you use CONCAT function it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So what is its value if the if statement above isn't executed?

If the `if` statement's condition is false and `set @year = 2005` is thus not executed, `@year` will keep whatever value it had just before the `if` statement. As there are no other `set @year` statements in your code snippet, `@year` will retain the value it was assigned at declaration point. And since the `declare @year` statement does not specify an initial value for the variable, `@year`, therefore, will be `NULL`.

> Can it be described as having a value?

Well, it depends upon whether you consider NULL a value, from the technical point of view. There is no general agreement on that point. If you regard it as an *undefined value*, then yes, `@year` could still be said to have a value. (In fact, a variable could then be said to *always* have a value.) If, however, you prefer to think of a NULL as an *absence of a value*, then apparently  the answer would be "no".

The reason why you could not see that it was NULL with the help of a PRINT statement is that NULLs are not printed. More specifically, `PRINT <an expression that evaluates to NULL>` produces an blank line, as you have already been told in the comments.